# TestRPC - Pythereum - No handlers could be found for logger "jsonrpc.manager"

Tags: truffle, pyethereum, testrpc

I am trying to get the standard init tests to work but I am getting the subject error. could you please help me to resolve this.

Thanks,

```
TestRPC/0.8.7/linux2/python2.7.12
```

## Available Accounts

0x82a978b3f5962a5b0957d9ee9eef472ee55b42f1
0x7d577a597b2742b498cb5cf0c26cdcd726d39e6e
0xdceceaf3fc5c0a63d195d69b1a90011b7b19650d
0x598443f1880ef585b21f1d7585bd0577402861e5
0x13cbb8d99c6c4e0f2728c7d72606e78a29c4e224
0x77db2bebba79db42a978f896968f4afce746ea1f
0x24143873e0e0815fdcbcffdbe09c979cbf9ad013
0x10a1c1cb95c92ec31d3f22c66eef1d9f3f258c6b
0xe0fc04fa2d34a66b779fd5cee748268032a146c0
0x90f0b1ebbba1c1936aff7aaf20a7878ff9e04b6c

Listening on localhost:8545

127.0.0.1 - - [2016-11-19 22:06:29] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 718 0.000745
127.0.0.1 - - [2016-11-19 22:06:29] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 718 0.000667
No handlers could be found for logger "jsonrpc.manager"
127.0.0.1 - - [2016-11-19 22:06:29] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 493 0.023480
127.0.0.1 - - [2016-11-19 22:06:29] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 718 0.000623
127.0.0.1 - - [2016-11-19 22:06:29] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 493 0.022910

Answer (score 3):

Adding below two lines to `bin/testrpc` file worked for me.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
```